# VECM in R: Testing weak exogeneity and imposing restrictions

Tags: r, time-series, error-correction, eviews, vector-auto-regression

I estimated **VECM** and would like to make 4 separate tests of **weak exogeneity** for each variable.

```
library(urca)
library(vars)

data(Canada)
               e     prod       rw     U
1980 Q1 929.6105 405.3665 386.1361  7.53
1980 Q2 929.8040 404.6398 388.1358  7.70
1980 Q3 930.3184 403.8149 390.5401  7.47
1980 Q4 931.4277 404.2158 393.9638  7.27
1981 Q1 932.6620 405.0467 396.7647  7.37
1981 Q2 933.5509 404.4167 400.0217  7.13
...

jt = ca.jo(Canada, type = "trace", ecdet = "const", K = 2, spec = "transitory")

t = cajorls(jt, r = 1)
t$rlm$coefficients
                  e.d       prod.d        rw.d         U.d
ect1     -0.005972228  0.004658649 -0.10607044 -0.02190508
e.dl1     0.812608320 -0.063226620 -0.36178542 -0.60482042
prod.dl1  0.208945048  0.275454380 -0.08418285 -0.09031236
rw.dl1   -0.045040603  0.094392696 -0.05462048 -0.01443323
U.dl1     0.218358784 -0.538972799  0.24391761 -0.16978208

t$beta
                  ect1
e.l1        1.00000000
prod.l1     0.08536852
rw.l1      -0.14261822
U.l1        4.28476955
constant -967.81673980
```

I guess that my equations are:

[image]

and I would like to test whether **alpha_e**, **alpha_prod**, **alpha_rw**, **alpha_U** (they marked red in the picture above) are zeros and impose necessary restrictions on my model. **So, my question is: how can I do it?**

I guess that my estimated **alphas** are:

```
                  e.d       prod.d        rw.d         U.d
ect1     -0.005972228  0.004658649 -0.10607044 -0.02190508
```

I guess that I should use **alrtest** function from **urca** library:

```
alrtest(z = jt, A = A1, r = 1)
```

and probably my **A** matrix for **alpha_e** should be like this:

```
A1 = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
     nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

The results of the test:

```
jt1 = alrtest(z = jt, A = A1, r = 1)
summary(jt1)

The value of the likelihood ratio test statistic:
0.48 distributed as chi square with 1 df.
The p-value of the test statistic is: 0.49

Eigenvectors, normalised to first column
of the restricted VAR:

                 [,1]
RK.e.l1        1.0000
RK.prod.l1     0.1352
RK.rw.l1      -0.1937
RK.U.l1        3.9760
RK.constant -960.2126

Weights W of the restricted VAR:

        [,1]
[1,]  0.0000
[2,]  0.0084
[3,] -0.1342
[4,] -0.0315
```

Which I guess means that I can't reject my hypothesis of weak exogeneity of **alpha_e**. And my new **alphas** here are: 0.0000, 0.0084, -0.1342, -0.0315.

Now the question is how can I impose this restriction on my **VECM** model?

If I do:

```
t1 = cajorls(jt1, r = 1)
t1$rlm$coefficients
                  e.d       prod.d        rw.d         U.d
ect1     -0.005754775  0.007717881 -0.13282970 -0.02848404
e.dl1     0.830418381 -0.049601229 -0.30644063 -0.60236338
prod.dl1  0.207857861  0.272499006 -0.06742147 -0.08561076
rw.dl1   -0.037677197  0.102991919 -0.05986655 -0.02019326
U.dl1     0.231855899 -0.530897862  0.30720652 -0.16277775
t1$beta
                 ect1
e.l1        1.0000000
prod.l1     0.1351633
rw.l1      -0.1936612
U.l1        3.9759842
constant -960.2126150
```

the new model don't have 0.0000, 0.0084, -0.1342, -0.0315 for **alphas**. It has -0.005754775  0.007717881 -0.13282970 -0.02848404 instead.

How can I get reestimated model with **alpha_e = 0**? I want reestimated model with **alpha_e = 0** because I would like to use it for predictions (**vecm** -> **vec2var** -> **predict**, but **vec2var** doesn't accept **jt1** directly). And in general - are calculations which I made correct or not?

Just for illustration, in **EViews** imposing restriction on **alpha** looks like this (not for this example):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1 cointegrating relationship (r=1), as it is in *t = cajorls(jt, r = 1)*,
your loading matrix can not have 4 rows and 3 columns:

```
A1 = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Matrix **A** can only have 4 rows and 1 column, if you have 4 variables and 1 cointegrating relationship.

Comment: To be honest, I am completely misunderstand how to construct A matrix. There are almost no information in the internet. Can you clarify how my A matrix should looks like if I want to test whether alpha_1 is equal to zero? How my A matrix should looks like if I want to test whether alpha_1 and alpha_3 are simultaneously equal to zero?